# Convert Bearing Degrees to Slope

Tags: quadratics, cartography

I'm working on a mapping application that sketches a graphic on the map. The user will input the distance of a line segment and provide a bearing for the line segment. For example, a line segment is 100 ft long and the second point on the segment has a bearing of 60 degrees (0 being north). How do I convert that 60 degrees to a slope so I can determine where the second point falls on a graph using a basic quadratic equation?

Comment: Use tangent. You'll need to recalculate the angle too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that or provide an example? My math skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: Sure, the angles in mathematics are calculated from the x-axis - effectively East - and increase counterclockwise, unlike bearings which typical have zero at North and increase clockwise. So you need to subtract a bearing angle from 90 to get a mathematical angle.

Comment: @JavaScript_Guru An answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494644/how-can-you-convert-a-bearing-to-a-gradient-in-r)